# Class object didnt get value from client

Tags: class, c#-4.0, post, wcf-rest

I am developing a WCF REST Service project.This is my Interface Service with AddNewEmployee service.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/AddNewEmployee", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
    bool AddNewEmployee(EmployeeDataContract emp);
```

Herer EmployeeDataContract is my class with variables and method implementation is like

```
 public bool AddNewEmployee(EmployeeDataContract employee)
    {           
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("D:\\EmployeeData.xml");

            doc.Element("DocumentElement").Add(
                    new XElement("Employees",
                    new XElement("EmployeeID", employee.EmployeeID),
                    new XElement("Name", employee.Name),
                    new XElement("JoiningDate", employee.JoiningDate),
                    new XElement("CompanyName", employee.CompanyName),
                    new XElement("Address", employee.Address)));

            doc.Save("D:\\EmployeeData.xml");
               return true;
        }
```

The problem is my class object didn't get values it shows empty value.
So whats wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with following steps and i got values in object-

1. Send object in body only in JSON format.
2. Set Content Type = application/json.
3. Method should be POST